# How do I use File::Slurp to write an array to a file with newlines?

Tags: perl

I am using File::Slurp to write to a file. The problem is that the array elements are being written as a single string on one line.  I would like to print array elements on separate lines.

I can always format my array elements to have a newline in each element, which I don't want to do.

Does File::Slurp support any options to print array elements on separate lines? I don't find any options in the documentation.

```
use File::Slurp;
my @input = ();

push (@input, "1:2");
push (@input, "a:b");

write_file("./out", @input);
```

Output looks like this

```
1:2a:b
```

I want

```
1:2
a:b
```

Comment: [The module uses a straight `join '', @_`](https://metacpan.org/source/URI/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#L366), so there's no option for appending newlines. For a small set, I'd just use `map` as suggested below. For a large set, you probably wouldn't be using File::Slurp anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer using map to appending new lines on my elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aSlurp) has an option to print array elements on separate lines.  Use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to add newlines to all your array elements.  This does not modify your array:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my @input = ();

push (@input, "1:2");
push (@input, "a:b");

write_file("./out", map { "$_\n" } @input);
```

Answer (score 7):

In this case, just set Perl's `$"` variable to `\n` and write the interpolated array to the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

local $" = "\n";

my @input = ();
push( @input, "1:2" );
push( @input, "a:b" );

write_file( "./out", "@input" );
```

Output to file:

```
1:2
a:b
```

Comment: one more newline => `"@input\n"`, or `qq{@input$"}`

Answer (score 5):

From [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm#SYNOPSIS)

```
write_file( $file_name, {atomic => 1}, map "$_=$conf{$_}\n", keys %conf ) ;
```